# How to achieve the following screen/layout in JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing

How to achieve this following kind of screen in java Swing -
[image]

I tried  to achieve the same but I could reach as below -
[image]

Suggest me the way to get the desired output.

Comment: By studying Swing/GUI-development? :)

Comment: The first screenshot is the main example of the javadocking library. You can download the example's source code and reach the same exact result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a docking based GUI.
I would recommend using docking framework for java like [flexdock](https://flexdock.dev.java.net/), [jdocking](https://jdocking.dev.java.net/) and [dockingframes](http://www.dock.javaforge.com).

We used dockinframes in our project, relatively professional.